# Autocomplete Custom Rendering with Screen Readers

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accessibility, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

I'm using jQuery to provide an autocomplete and overriding `_renderItem` to render a bit more detail, but when trying to test this with JAWS, it seems to read only the value in the `data-value` attribute:

```
$("#UnitName").autocomplete({
    ...
    create: function () {
        $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            return $('<li class="place-ac">')
                .attr("data-value", item.value)
                .append('<span class="placename">' + item.label + '</span> (<span class="postcode">' + item.postcode + '</span>)<span class="provider">' + place.organisation + '</span>')
                .appendTo(ul);
        }
    },
    minLength: 0,
});
```

Resulting in this rendered HTML:

```
<li class="place-ac ui-menu-item" data-value="61327" id="ui-id-148" tabindex="-1">
    <span class="place-name">Rear Garden</span> (<span class="postcode">XX1 1XX</span>)<span class="provider">Cherry Orchard Garage</span>
</li>
```

JAWS will read `61327`. Is there a way to specify an extra attribute for JAWS to use?